# How to remove a section from an INI file using Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, configuration, ini, file-processing

I would like to remove a section and also key values under the section from an INI file using Win32 API.

Can somebody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: The documentation tells you how to do it. Can't you simply follow that documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete the section and all the entries you will use the somewhat counter-intuitive function named [WritePrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725501(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `lpKeyName` parameter set to `NULL`. This will delete the entire section stored in the `lpAppName` field, including all the entries.